# "wurde ... Jahre alt" für gestorbene Person

Tags: verb, usage

Aus dem [*Spiegel-Online*](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/junior-malanda-vom-vfl-wolfsburg-ist-nach-autounfall-tot-a-1012359.html):

> Er **wurde** nur 20 Jahre alt: Junior Malanda ist bei einem Autounfall ums Leben gekommen. Der Bundesligaspieler vom VfL Wolfsburg saß selbst nicht am Steuer des Unglückswagens.

Warum wird "wurde" statt "war" verwendet? Wurde er *gerade* 20 Jahre alt?

Comment: Man könnte auch sagen: Er war **erst** 20 Jahre alt. Grammatikalisch erklären kann ich das aber auch nicht, hier müsste man den genauen Unterschied zwischen *nur* und *erst* recherchieren.

Comment: A person's age, ie the time that has elapsed since their birth, is often floored (ie rounded down) for convenience. The negation of the statement - `Er wurde [=ist geworden] nicht nur 20 Jahre alt` - is definitely not right,so the original statement has got some merit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das *Er wurde nur 20 Jahre alt* hat in meinem Sprachgefühl einen stärkeren Ausdruck des Bedauerns als *Er war erst 20 Jahre alt*. Da klingt IMHO etwas mehr mit, daß eigentlich noch das ganze Leben vor ihm lag, als er so früh starb.

Die Bedeutung mit *gerade 20* ist hier nicht gemeint.

Comment: "Er wurde gerade einmal 20 Jahre alt." wiederum würde gehen - und auch so ziemlich das gleiche ausdrücken.

Comment: @Gerhard, ich glaube `boaten` meint das in der Bedeutung, *er hat gerade (vor kurzem) seinen zwangigsten Geburtstag gehabt*. Das ist aber IMHO nicht gemeint.

Comment: agreed. Just wanted to mention, that the use of "gerade" is possible, and maybe it helps boaten to understand the meaning of "wurde" better

Comment: Gerhard ok, Du hast schon auch Recht. Ist nicht immer einfach, die Feinheiten der Sprache rauszuklabüsern.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man „er wurde nur 20 Jahre alt“ sagt, hat man sein gesamtes Leben im Sinn und will ausdrücken, dass er nur diese 20 Jahre hatte. Im Beispiel weiß der Leser dies schon vor dem Doppelpunkt, bevor also der Tod erwähnt wird. Hätte dort „war“ gestanden, wäre die Aussage zusammen mit dem Teil nach dem Doppelpunkt gewesen, dass er 20 Jahre alt war, als er starb. Die Information wäre die gleiche, der Fokus ein anderer.

Comment: +1 für gesamtes Leben. So lese ich es auch. Die Verwendung von `war` ist weniger abschließend.

Answer (score 0):

Wie du bereits richtig erkannt hast, wird **wurde** im Sinne von **gerade** verwendet; durch die Partikel **nur** wird die Bedeutung auf **gerade mal** abgeändert. Durch diese Kombination erhält das Ganze auch Vergangenheitscharakter und wie auch @Karl bereits angemerkt hat, erhält es einen zusätzlichen Ausdruck des Bedauerns.

Um auch noch auf den Kommentar Bezug zu nehmen: Zwischen **[nur](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_denn_doch)** und **[erst](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erst_aber_eben)** als Partikel in diesem Zusammenhang ist kein allzu großer Unterschied. Also ja, **wurde nur** und **war erst** funktionieren beide, jedoch verliert das Zweite etwas an Wirkung im Zusammenhang mit Vergangenheit und Bedauern.

Answer (score 0):

Die Information "20 Jahre" kann zwei Bedeutungen haben:

> 1. Bei `seinem` Tod war `er` x Jahre alt. (Zeitpunkt)
> 2. Bis zum `seinem` Tod hatte `er` x Jahre gelebt. (Zeitspanne)

In beiden Fällen können natürlich noch `gerade mal`, `nur`, `erst` oder ähnliches anhängen, um mit der Aussage eine Trauer / ein Bedauern auszudrücken.

Comment: Das war aber nicht die Frage.